# MGRS: Algorithms for getting all the 100km squares in a Grid zone designator

Tags: mgrs

I have an MGRS grid zone designator (i.e. 12S), and need to determine if a given 100km square identifier (ie WA, WH) is contained in that zone designator. Alternatively, a method for getting all of the square identifiers within a given grid zone designator would work. Does such an algorithm exist?

Comment: But using what tool? Do you need a script or a formula?

Comment: Either a script or a formula would work. I will be implementing it in C#.

Comment: So for example given "4Q" you want all the two-letter squares inside 4Q in this diagram: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/MGRSgridOriginSchemeAA.png  - including partial squares?

Comment: @Spacedman Yes. That is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

No such algorythm exists publically that i know of.

So you will have to make one. Here is just one API development roadmap for you to follow:

1. Gather the MGRS spatial data (from U of Florida for example)
2. Create a spatial database server, say from Postgres
3. Load the data into Pg
4. Create an API project that accesses the spatial data using supplied inputs
5. Create a collection of test cases to ensure API is operating correctly.

An alternative would be to determine analytically the pattern of 100ks within all of the grids, then query this within API.